# Stop time interval during navigation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

Currently i am using angular js

I have one get method to get data from server side in `default.html` page

```
function bindActiveLoans() {
            $http.get(rootUrlSingleEscaped + '/cooperativa/allunfundedloans/?authId=' + userInfo.UserId)
                 .success(function (response) {
                     if (response.Loans.length == 0) {
                         $scope.IsValues = false;
                         $scope.$apply();
                         return true;
                     }
                     $scope.IsValues = true;
                     $scope.unfundedLoans = response;
                 });
        };

        setInterval(function () {
            $scope.$apply(bindActiveLoans());
        }, 5000);
```

The above function helps to get the data from server side method in every 5 seconds.

Here, I  have an issue.

Additionally I have some more pages, like

- default2.html,default3.html,default4.html,default5.html.

  > The timer is still running while i navigation `default.html` page to `default1.html` page. I want to only that timer running in `default.html` page.If i go to another page,then the timer should stop. How can we achieve it?

Comment: Do you mean, if you have all five pages open in 5 windows/tabs, only one should be invoking a timer? If not, timers will automatically stop when you navigate from one page to another...

Comment: yup, absolutely correct. I want to clearInterval in default page,When i navigate from default page to another page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the angularjs example in the [$interval API page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

```
    var interval = $interval(function() {
        console.log('say hello');
    }, 1000);

    $interval.cancel(interval);
```

With $interval.cancel(var) you can stop the interval and if you want to stop it when navigating to another page you should try something like this.

```
var interval = null;

module.controller('SomeController', '$interval', function($interval) {
    interval = $interval(function() {
        ...
    }, 2000);
}).run(['$rootScope', '$interval', function($rootScope, $interval) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `$routeChangeStart` event and do the clearing of the interval depending on the route parameters,

```
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
           if(<next is not default.aspx>){
           // clear interval here
            }
  });
```

Comment: great. I will try this way.

Answer (score -1):

call clearInterval function when navigating from default page

e.g.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
        $scope.$apply(bindActiveLoans());
    }, 5000);


function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Call myStopFunction

Comment: Can you give any sample code? I want to clearInterval in default page

Comment: How can i write navigating  event in default page?